# Why does CQRS seem to prevent unique constraints on write side?

Tags: indexing, unique, cqrs

Everywhere I see a post about ensuring uniqueness in a CQRS architecture the most obvious solution for me which is to add a unique index on the write side is never mentioned, without any explanation.

Instead I read the read model must be queried for that, and concurrency issues should be tackled by a saga compensating the action. Seems overly complex when you can just reject the command on unique index violation, so why is that?

Comment: How exactly are you thinking about adding an unique index on the write side? Where? CQRS with or without Event sourcing?

Comment: My write model is a database so I can add a unique indexes on the fields I want. Let's say users email if that's important. And let's say without event sourcing if this is too.

Comment: it's relevant to specify, i.e. with ES you do not have a flat database for the write model

Comment: In CQRS without ES is valid and OK what you are proposing

Comment: Does that mean the most simple and obvious solution is never considered because of the possibility of a write model unable to enforce unicity? Why would it be invalid with ES?

Comment: but it is considered all the time

Comment: with ES: where do you put the unique index?

Comment: I didn't find *any* article where this is mentioned. Why would event sourcing prevent me to put an index on unique fields??

Comment: it does not prevent but it is harder because the event stores do not have this option. This means that you need to put the unique index on another database which means in another transaction which is bad-ish

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179009/discussion-between-matthecat-and-constantin-galbenu).

Comment: It is hard with ES because you need to ensure both write operations (unique index and persisting events) succeed as an atomic operation. I wrote a blog article about decoupling CQRS and ES, it might be interesting for you: https://medium.com/@mbue/some-thoughts-on-using-cqrs-without-event-sourcing-938b878166a2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does CQRS seem to prevent unique constraints on write side?

It doesn't

What it does do is recognize that that maintaining an invariant on a distributed set is a nightmare.

> the most obvious solution for me which is to add a unique index on the write side is never mentioned, without any explanation

That's right.  If you don't have a distributed set -- if all of the elements of the set are stored together -- then maintaining the invariant is straight forward.

But what does it mean to have a unique index constraint that spans two databases?

To express the idea in more modern terms, the guiding assumption is that the business logic should be [scale agnostic](https://web.archive.org/web/20150319012745if_/http://adrianmarriott.net:80/logosroot/papers/LifeBeyondTxns.pdf).  If two write models are *really* independent of one another, then we ought to be able to store them separately.

If there is a constraint that needs to be satisfied that depends on data from two different write models, then those write models aren't really independent.

[Greg Young raised](https://web.archive.org/web/20101221183328/http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/08/12/eventual-consistency-and-set-validation/) a really good question

> What is the business impact of having a failure?

That's the sort of thing we are supposed to be thinking about in domain driven design, after all.

> Why would event sourcing prevent me to put an index on unique fields??

Same answer really: it doesn't, *so long as your unique constraint and your events are stored together*.

If you have an RDMBS with a table that represents the elements of your set, and tables that store your events, you can update the two tables together within a single transaction, and roll back the whole mess if your constraint is violated.

But take that same idea, and put the set in a *different* database than the events?  Now you have two distinct transactions to coordinate.  Good luck with that.